# How would I solve for the s_\alpha or s_r vectors using components from the listed E-Frame? Space Vehicle Dynamics

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm taking a dynamics class where we are specifically focusing on the transport theorem. I need to first identify the position vector, and then take 2 derivatives for inertial velocity and inertial acceleration. While I understand how that works, there's one step in the solution to the problem below that I do not currently follow.

[Dynamics Problem in question that contains 3 frames, a telescoping rod, and a circle of radius r. These are both rotating CCW about the origin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yj4O.png)

The image link below is the worked solution to the problem.

[Worked correct solution to the above problem statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efRIO.png)

While I understand the concept as a whole, there's one step that my professor didn't go into much detail about, which is the focus of this post. I shared a screenshot below focusing on the s_\alpha portion but the derivation of s_r based on the E-Frame is also confusing.

[E-frame with s alpha vector relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APmtm.png)

Could someone help me out with a quick explainer on how to derive these vectors from components of the E-Frame?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm confused about how the two vectors in the E-frame in the image can combine into the s_\alpha vector using sin and cos. My professor skipped the step in his lecture and I wasn't able to get my question in during class.